# Upper bound for the number of roots of a given order.

Tags: polynomials

Let $q$ be  a prime, $l>1$ an integer such that $l\mid q-1$, and $p_l(X)=1+X+X^2+\dots+X^{l-1}$ a polynomial with coefficients in $(\Bbb Z/q\Bbb Z)^\times$. Is there an upper bound to (if not a closed form for) the number of roots of $p_l(X)$ in $(\Bbb Z/q\Bbb Z)^\times$ *with order $l$*? For example, for $q=13$ and $l=6$, $p_6(X)$ has the following roots in $(\Bbb Z/13\Bbb Z)^\times$: $3,4,9,10,12$; but only $4$ and $10$ have order $6$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every element of multiplicative order $\ell$ is a root of $p_\ell(X)$ since $X^\ell-1 = (X-1)p_\ell(x)$. So the question is simply asking how many elements of order $\ell$ there are modulo the prime $q$. Since the multiplicative group $(\Bbb Z/q\Bbb Z)^\times$ is cyclic of order $q-1$, the answer is exactly $\phi(\ell)$ (the Euler phi function) if $\ell\mid(q-1)$ and $0$ if $\ell\nmid(q-1)$.